# Why do transactions sent by a channel account do not appear in the operations history for the source account?

Tags: transactions, horizon, multi-sig, channel

I'm currently writing an app that facilitates multi-sig transactions, and one of the issues we faced was the fact that to enable multiple transactions to be created and signed, we had to use channel accounts in order to avoid having the wrong sequence number for a transaction e.g If we created two transactions using the multi-sig accounts sequence number, we would fall into a sequencing issue if we submitted the second transaction before the first one.

This is working great, however when you get the operations for an account (e.g `/accounts/{multi_sig_account_id}/operations`) it doesn't show the operations from the transaction submitted using the channel account.

It's odd because the transaction shows up when I look get the transactions for the account ( `/accounts/{multi_sig_account_id}/transactions` ), however it's a not really a useful endpoint as it doesnt show information about each operation in the transaction.

Is this intended behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when you get the operations for an account (e.g /accounts/{multi_sig_account_id}/operations) it doesn't show the operations from the transaction submitted using the channel account.

I guess it's because you apply operations to the channel accounts, so neither of operations are applied directly to the "multi_sig_account". Therefore, such operations shouldn't be displayed by `/accounts/{multi_sig_account_id}/operations` endpoint. It's hard to tell without a context; a link to an example tx would be helpful.

> however it's a not really a useful endpoint as it doesnt show information about each operation in the transaction.

Actually, you **can** retrieve operations from the transaction. Just convert `envelope_xdr` to the transaction object.

```
const tx = new StellarSdk.Transaction(envelope_xdr)
console.log(tx.operations)
```

Comment: Here's an example transaction 

https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions/c1b5296332e163eef990402455658f143f594472b9a1a03bb518362e309de280


if you click on the envelope xdr you can see the source account for the transaction is the channel account but the source account for the payment operation is GAM2YDZ234OYBN3VYL7WU2ZULJHKSOLSBHFWGTK3DUGKMZQ4HSF7KL4F (the multisig account).


Thanks for the tip, I knew how to get the operations from a envelope, however I didn't want to have to loop through all of the transactions items. I thought using the operations endpoint made more sense

Comment: https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?input=AAAAADFnhYFAuHSXSwegIz1SyY9RZSvAbyWu%2FnmdmLA%2FNLweAAAAyAAVbgUAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAQAAAAAZrA863x2At3XC%2F2prNFpOqTlyCctjTVsdDKZmHDyL9QAAAAEAAAAAjKAMyUz9c%2B7%2FUx6VTHfgB%2BJXyHLR8i2FeS4yFgwREnMAAAAAAAAAAAH3ikAAAAAAAAAACAAAAABZbBx9fnhXAw5ZHuJp1LxgPCLNnqI83X3pcaRXy5UulwAAAAAAAAACPzS8HgAAAEDK4ZPQkURQ57fYe6m4hwpjiTU1TWNcmDN3Jk41OR9GOFyrjJbXe8hKpDH4r0zrIsJtnklG1IV6M69rc6Gd4eIC0drbrwAAAEBg4feCBnejGG2MLbb%2FXk8wa4wJwNIk4TwUFcqLOrPJm37dQymZscEYKUipt6kjPNEr%2FxtOJOgNz6bx60ScwkkC&type=TransactionEnvelope&network=test 

here's the link to env

Comment: Looks like `GB7OTX...LN26C4K ` is your multi-sig account. But it is neither a channel or source account of the tx (merely one more signature **keypair**), so naturally the `operations` endpoint won't show the operations for it. Have you tried using `GAM2YD...HSF7KL4F` as a multi-sig account? In that case you'll get exactly what you want from `/account/GAM2YD...HSF7KL4F/operations`. Maybe even there is no need to change anything in the signature schema if `GAM2YD...HSF7KL4F` is a source account for all your operations.

Comment: Sorry I should've been more clear; `GAM2YD...HSF7KL4F` is the multisig account, `GB7OTX...LN26C4K` is one of the signers for the multi-sig account, and `GAYWPB...7GS6B4INX` is the channel account. looking at `/accounts/GAM2YD...HSF7KL4F/operations` doesn't show the **payment operation** where the source is `GAM2YD...HSF7KL4F`, but looking at `/accounts/GAM2YD...HSF7KL4F/transactions` does show the transaction where the source account for the **payment operation** is `GAM2YD...HSF7KL4F`

Comment: But it [is there](https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GAM2YDZ234OYBN3VYL7WU2ZULJHKSOLSBHFWGTK3DUGKMZQ4HSF7KL4F/operations?order=desc) (operation 6031980919525377). Just set larger page size (`?limit=200`) or descendant sort order(`?order=desc`). Horizon displays only 10 entries by default.

Comment: Oh wow lol that's pretty stupid of me, this whole time I thought the default limit was 20 not 10. Thanks a lot man!